# Testing Meteor application with Chimp/Mocha - automatic login to test authenticated routes

Tags: meteor, webdriver, mocha.js, mailchimp

I'm testing some forms in a Meteor application using Mocha. The routes in the application are authenticated, so only logged in users or users who have a role of 'administrator' can view them.

When the test opens the browser to view the url and fill the form in, it gets redirected to the login page as expected.

Is there a way to automatically log the user in before doing the test so I don't have to remove the route authentication?

Here's the test code so far

```
describe( 'Create a Client', function() {
    it( 'should create a new client @watch', function() {
        browser.url('http://localhost:3000/dashboard/clients/new')

       [...]

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
function login(user) {
  browser.url('http://localhost:3000')
  browser.executeAsync(function(user, done) {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(user.username, user.password, done)
  }, user)

}

// now you can do this:
login({
  username: 'someone',
  password: 'aSecret'
});
browser.url('http://localhost:3000/dashboard/clients/new')
```

Note that you need to make sure the user exists first, and for that you can use fixtures.

See here for more info:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-how-can-i-wait-for-before-hooks-to-finish-when-testing-with-chimp-meteor-cucumber/18356/12

Comment: Quick question, I've implemented the code exactly as you instructed. I've changed the username/password, however the second 'browser.url' function isn't working. Once the user is logged in the app stays at the dashboard and the test fails. Any idea why?